# What is wrong with my if block?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, if-statement

Everything on my program work except this.  I don't see what the problem is.  I need the program to spit out a error message if the user inputs more than 25 grades.  here is my code

```
package my.meancalculator;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MeanCalcUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
private double gradeAverage;
private double standardDeviation;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private double[] gradeArray = new double[25];
private int numberOfGradesInput = 0;


public MeanCalcUI() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public double getAverage(double[] gradeArray, int numberOfGradesInput) {

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGradesInput; i++) {
        sum = sum + gradeArray[i];
    }

    return (sum / numberOfGradesInput);
}

public double getStdDev(double[] gradeArray, int numberOfGradesInput, double average) {

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGradesInput; i++) {
        sum = sum + Math.pow((gradeArray[i] - average), 2);
    }

    return Math.sqrt(sum / numberOfGradesInput);
}


private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void btnEnterGradesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    if (numberOfGradesInput > 25) {
        // We've already finished entering the max # of grades
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "You can only input 25 grades!",
                "Too much data!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;         
    }
    do {
        String gradeInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Enter Grade",
                "Enter Grade",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        // When we receive empty/null input, we're done entering grades
        if (gradeInput == null || gradeInput.length() == 0) {
            break;
        }

        double gradeValue = 0; // Set to avoid 'may be unset' compiler error
        try {
            gradeValue = Double.parseDouble(gradeInput);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "Your input must be numeric!",
                    "Bad Data!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            continue; // start over again
        }

        // Put the grade into the array and update the number of grades entered
        gradeArray[numberOfGradesInput] = gradeValue;
        numberOfGradesInput++;

        // Add to the grade total
        txtNumGrades.setText(formatter.format(numberOfGradesInput));

        //use the getAverage method to get the average of the grades
        gradeAverage = getAverage(gradeArray, numberOfGradesInput);
        txtMean.setText(formatter.format(gradeAverage));

        //use the getStdDev method to get the standard deviation
        standardDeviation = getStdDev(gradeArray, numberOfGradesInput, gradeAverage);
        txtStdDeviation.setText(formatter.format(standardDeviation));
    } while (numberOfGradesInput < 25);



}
```

I used my whole code in case it was something outside the if that is causing this.  Every time I run the program and I a number more than 25 times the window where it asks for the user input closes and no error message pops up.  Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: the if is outside of the do..while loop

Comment: Nope, not that. That was one of the first things I tried and it still did not pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your condition to `>=`, as your do/while asks for 25 grades, after that your condition will still be false and you'll enter loop again and will get out of bounds exception

```
if (numberOfGradesInput >= 25)
```

Comment: That would make it if numberOfGrades is greater than or equal to 25.  The user is allowed to enter up to 25 grades but not any more.

Comment: @Akira That's why you need to check if they've *already entered 25*. `if (numberOfGradesInput > 25)` checks if they've *already entered more than 25*.

Answer (score 0):

think you need to change your condition to >=, as your do/while asks for 25 grades, after that your condition will still be false and you'll enter loop again and will get out of bounds exception

```
if (numberOfGradesInput >= 25)
```

when your button action is fired it should check if it is greater than or equal to 25. between your if statement and your while loop you have a use case that is not covered.

What if the number of grades is 25?  with the code you've written it will skip over your if-statement and enter your do-while loop and add the "26th grade" (actually cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException instead of printing out the error dialog.

Comment: I changed it to like you said and it did not make a difference.  It didn't add the 26th number either, it just stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your condition and do while. I tried to do the least modification to your code to make it working .

```
        do {
            if (numberOfGradesInput >= 25) {
                // We've already finished entering the max # of grades
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "You can only input 25 grades!",
                        "Too much data!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            else{
                //....
             }
         } while (numberOfGradesInput < 26);
```

Comment: It is incremented in the do-while loop.

Comment: I actually did numberOfGrades++... The problem is that when I type in 25 grades the error message does not pop up, I have to click the action button again in order for it to pop up

Comment: I modified my comment please look, If you require clean or proper code let me know